# How can I pass a List to another class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a list in this file called check_symptoms.dart which the list is called _chosenItems
i want it to pass it to another file which is a stateful widget
here's my code for Check_symptoms.dart

```
import 'package:diagnose_app/results.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class SymptomsChecker extends StatefulWidget {
  const SymptomsChecker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SymptomsChecker> createState() => _SymptomsCheckerState();
}

class _SymptomsCheckerState extends State<SymptomsChecker> {
  List _items = [];
  List _itemsForDisplay = [];
  List _chosenItems = [];
  int maxheight = 0;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/Symptoms.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    setState(() {
      _items = data["Symptoms"];
      _itemsForDisplay = _items;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    readJson();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 105, 120, 255),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // Display the data loaded from sample.json
            // _ListChosenItem(23),
            SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            _searchBar(),
            Divider(
              height: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return _ListItem(index);
                },
                itemCount: _itemsForDisplay.length,
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 2,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              child: LimitedBox(
                maxHeight: 200,
                child: Scrollbar(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Wrap(
                      children: _chosenItems.map((item) {
                        //print(_chosenItems);
                        return chosenItems(item);
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: 10,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                              // sending chosenItems to results.dart
                        builder: (context) => Results(list: _chosenItems)));
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Find Results",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Padding chosenItems(item) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return ElevatedButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _itemsForDisplay.add(item);
              //_items.add(item);
              _chosenItems.remove(item);
            });
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              textStyle:
                  const TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
          label: Text(item),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.remove_circle,
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 217, 216),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  _searchBar() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 244, 244, 244),
            hintText: 'Search Symptoms'),
        style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 22, 25, 52)),
        maxLines: 1,
        onChanged: (text) {
          text = text.toLowerCase();
          setState(() {
            _itemsForDisplay = _items.where((item) {
              var itemEntity = item.toLowerCase();
              return itemEntity.contains(text);
            }).toList();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _ListItem(index) {
    return Wrap(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _chosenItems.add(_itemsForDisplay[index]);
              _itemsForDisplay.removeAt((index));
              //_items.removeAt((index));
            });
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              textStyle:
                  const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
          child: Text(_itemsForDisplay[index]),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _ListChosenItem(index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Wrap(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
            child: Text(_chosenItems[index]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here's the way I'm receiving the list in results.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Results extends StatefulWidget {
  final List list;
  const Results({required this.list});

  @override
  State<Results> createState() => _ResultsState(list);
}

class _ResultsState extends State<Results> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(list);
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

this line of code of results.dart

```
State<Results> createState() => _ResultsState(list);
```

is says:

> List list Type: List
> package:diagnose_app/results.dart
>
> Don't put any logic in createState.dartno_logic_in_create_state Too
> many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. Try removing the
> extra arguments.

Am I passing the list in a wrong way? thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, an instance of `State` can access the members of its parent `StatefulWidget` via the `widget` property.

So your particular problem can be solved simply by accessing `widget.list`, you don't need to pass the list explicitly to `_ResultsState`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Results extends StatefulWidget {
  final List list;
  const Results({required this.list});

  @override
  State<Results> createState() => _ResultsState();
}

class _ResultsState extends State<Results> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.list);
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

But further, if you do want to explicitly pass a value to a class constructor, you'll need to add the field as a member to the class and define the constructor that takes that value.